# GeoDNS routing on Google Cloud Load Balancer with Google App Engine as backend

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are looking to use Google App Engine for one of our low latency service. We are required to provide low latency service across the globe. Since Google App Engine is a regional service and there is no straight forward way to deploy it multi-regional. So, looking at Google Load Balancer to route at DNS level, but that also does not seems to be possible as load balancer not supporting App Engine as a backend service. Is there any other way to achieve GeoDNS routing in GCP for App Engine service.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an direct way to achieve GeoDNS routing since App Engine is a regional service, as you said.

Read [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70604631) to have further insight on this. In the second comment they state the two possible workarounds, useful for both standard and flexible environments:

> 1. The workaround is how you mentioned, using a single project with a load balancer to route requests to Compute Engine instances in
>      different regions. Then have each Compute Engine instance act as
>      proxies to an App Engine project in each of the different regions
>      (where you would copy your code to each App Engine project).
> 2. It may be easier in the meantime to use [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) instead of App Engine for multi-regional application serving.

You could star the FR to support it.